Consecutive index/match issue
I haven't seen any post with somenthing I could use, so I hope it is not repeated.
I'm working on a Excel 2010 sheet that should look for a date (row 3), cross it with a marked cell (coded tv) and, finally, find a name in column A.
The goal is to select a date and find which name has the code "TV" on that day.
The formula in the image is the one I'm working on right now. It is a modification from another I found here.
INDEX(INDEX($A$4:$A$37;0;MATCH(B39;$P$3:$BW$3;0));MATCH($F$42;INDEX(P:BW;0;MATCH(B39;$P$3:$BW$3;0)-1);0)) 

This is the formula ready to use (and translated to english excel), but doesn't work. It gives me a #ref! error on the first INDEX. I believe that it is a problem with the order of commands, but I should admit that it is over my programming knowledge.
My older version of this formula is able to do something similar (it finds a name), but it doesn't care about the tag "TV".
=INDEX($A$4:$A$37;MATCH(B39;$P$3:$BW$3;0);MATCH($F$42;P4:P37;0))

I have a primitive version of this formula that works, but it is column related and quite slow to update the whole calendar
=INDEX('2024'!$A$4:$A$37;MATCH("TV";'2024'!X$4:X$37;0))

The one I'm looking for should be able to find the person for any given day, by itself.


Hi Marcus. Please post some sample data showing your expected output.

In your question you say you lookup a date in row 2, but your formula matches row 3

Sorry. It's my first question and I made a lot of mistakes. I did (tried to, at least) attach a picture, but somehow, I cannot see it either (so it didn't upload), and yes, I said I was looking for the date on row 2 when the formula called row 3. I ammending those errors.

=INDEX($A$3:$A$39,MATCH("TV",INDEX($P$3:$BW$39,,MATCH($B$1,$P$3:$BW$3,0)),0),)
First this checks for the column:
INDEX($P$3:$BW$39,,MATCH($B$1,$P$3:$BW$3,0)),0),)
Next this is wrapped in another index/match, where the column A values are indexed and your indexed column is matched against TV

Thank you very much! it worked!
I understand that I didn't give the whole picture so some references you couldn't know where they led. I'm sorry.

Find name for selected date for "TV":
As CSE formula for all dates:
=SI.ERROR(INDICE($A$3:$A$20;COINCIDIR("TV";INDICE($A$3:$K$20;0;COLUMNA());0));"")

or
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$20,MATCH("TV",INDEX($A$3:$K$20,0,COLUMN()),0)),"")



=LET(
    data, $A$2:$L$20,
    date_input, $B$1,
    dates, INDEX(data, 1, ),
    INDEX(
        data,
        MATCH(
            "TV",
            INDEX(data, 0, MATCH(date_input, dates, 0))
        ),
        1
    )
)

